# Screenshot without Ram increasing constantly - Disposing of objects after use

Tags: vb.net, winforms, dispose

I have a VB.Net application that has a form with a button and picture box on it. When I click the button it takes a screenshot of the laptops screen, adds a cursor, loads it in to the PictureBox and saves it as a JPG file.

This works as expected, however the RAM will increase every time the button is clicked and never release any of the RAM used by the click of the button.  I believe this is due to the bitmap objects not being disposed of after use. However I am unsure on how to do this. I have tried things such as `PictureBox1.Dispose()` at the end.

I have also found articles that suggest that instead of `Dim graph as graphics`, I should declare the `Graphics` object with a `Using` statement, as in: `Using graph as Graphics`.
However this doesn't work for me either.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
  'THIS PART TAKES A SCREENSHOT 
  Dim area As Rectangle
  Dim graph As Graphics
  area = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
  captured = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        graph = Graphics.FromImage(captured)
        graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, 0, 0, area.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

  'HERE WE INSERT THE MOUSE CURSOR
  Cursor.Draw(graph, New Rectangle(New Point(Cursor.Position.X - Cursor.HotSpot.X, Cursor.Position.Y - Cursor.HotSpot.Y), Cursor.Size))

  'AND WE PUT THE PICTURE IN A PICTUREBOX
  PictureBox1.Image = captured
  PictureBox1.Image.Save("C:\temp\screenshot.jpg")
End Sub
```

Any ideas would be appreciated on how I can get this running and releasing all RAM after it completes the screenshot saving on the last line of code.

Comment: `PictureBox1.Image = captured` doesn't dispose the previous image if there is one there, so you should check, and then call `PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()`  `I should be "using graph as Graphics" instead`  Yes, you should, because then it will automatically dispose the `graph` object for you.

Comment: I have added the picture to load on Form 1_Load and therefore I have been able to add the PictureBox1.Image.Dispose() to call which helps. Thanks!

Unfortunately when changing the "dim graph as graphics" to "Using graph as graphics"  I get errors such as 'Using' resource variable must have an explicit initialization" and "'using must end with matching 'end using'" Any ideas on how this would work for my code? Thanks again!

Comment: Add `captured?.Dispose()` before `captured = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(...)` (that's your Image, not the PictureBox.Image), then change `Using graph = Graphics.FromImage(captured) [...] End Using` and move the rest of the code inside the `Using` block. Then `captured.Save("C:\temp\screenshot.jpg")` <- as mentioned, `captured` is your Bitmap, the control just shows it. ++ If you don't dispose of the Graphics object you create, the memory usage will keep growing. If you follow this pattern, the memory usage, except the initial allocations (a few bytes), won't grow at all.

Comment: I have added the caputre.dispose() and also the "Using Graph = Graphics.FromImage(captured)" + "End Using" at the end. I now get the following error:'ReadOnly' variable cannot be the target of an assignment. It is pointing to the " graph = Graphics.FromImage(captured)" line.

Comment: Not `capture.dispose()`, but `capture?.dispose()`: you need to assume that the Bitmap object could be null. -- You should have `Private captured As Bitmap = Nothing` there.

Comment: Update your question to show what you actually wrote (all parts). BTW, what's `Cursor.Draw()` used for? `CopyFromScreen` already captures the Mouse Pointer.

Comment: Code Updated, I have nulled out the following: 'graph = Graphics.FromImage(captured)

which was the line causing the issue. It will now run however the screenshot is just a black screen.

Comment: `captured?.Dispose()` and `captured = New Bitmap(...)` of course are called **outside** the `Using` block (before it), along with `Dim area = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`. -- Already mentioned: `captured.Save("C:\temp\screenshot.jpg")`. The PictureBox is a Presentation element, your Bitmap is represented by the `capture` object.

Comment: Hi Jimi, that restructure seemed to work. Thanks so much! I have updated my code in the question to the working code.

Comment: You should post that code as an answer.  I rolled the question back to the previous state so it remains a question.

Comment: It's a good thing if you do what @LarsTech suggested. This way, you can post and describe your findings, maybe a comparison of what the memory consumption was before and what is now. You could also show screenshots or animations of the Diagnostic Tools pane, to demonstrate the memory state in these two setups.

Comment: Reverted back to the original post, since the last edit contained just coding mistakes that doesn't make sense to show anymore.  -- BTW, when you write this: `captured.Save("D:\temp2\screenshot.jpg")`, you save a PNG, not a JPEG. Write `captured.Save(path, ImageFormat.Jpeg)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'THIS PART TAKES A SCREENSHOT 
    Dim path As String
    path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "screenshot.jpg")

    If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
    Dim area As Rectangle
    Using captured As Drawing.Bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Using graph As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(captured)
            area = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
            graph.CopyFromScreen(area.X, area.Y, 0, 0, area.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)
            Cursor.Draw(graph, New Rectangle(New Point(Cursor.Position.X - Cursor.HotSpot.X, Cursor.Position.Y - Cursor.HotSpot.Y), Cursor.Size))
            captured.Save(path, Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path)
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```